# How many levels from Rayman Origins are availabe in Rayman Legends?

Tags: rayman-legends

I've unlocked several of the "Back to Origins" paintings/levels in *Rayman Legends*.  I've never played *Rayman Origins* and was wondering how many of the levels from that game are included in *Rayman Legends*.  All some? Can I save myself $20 by playing *Rayman Legends* to completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legends has 40 of the levels from Origins, remastered with tweaks here and there. "...bringing the majority of Rayman Origins into the upcoming sequel." and "The levels are handpicked to highlight the best levels of Rayman Origins." seem to indicate that unless you really want to get every last bit of Origins, Legends is all you'll need.

Source: http://www.gametrailers.com/side-mission/56980/rayman-legends-gets-more-game-with-remastered-origins-content